# ¿Como usar str para lineas de archivo en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, archivo

Al leer las líneas del archivo, siempre se leen como últimos caracteres, algunos caracteres blancos como espacios y el carácter de cambio de lí­nea ('\n'). Esto hace que los nombres de archivos creados incluyan estos caracteres adicionales. Por ejemplo aquí:

```
archivo_usuario = open(nombre+".user","w")
archivo_usuario.write(nombre+"\n")
```

¿Qué métodos de `str` puedo usar para que no se lean los últimos espacios en blanco o salto de línea ('\n')?

Comment: En el titulo de la pregunta parece sobrar alguna palabra, y no veo la relación entre el título y el contenido. Por otro lado, en el cuerpo del contenido no encuentro ninguna pregunta. Supongo que la cuestión es cómo evitar esos blancos y retornos de carro. Tan sencillo como usar `nombre.strip()` en lugar de `nombre`.

Comment: Si, en realidad quería preguntar que métodos de str puedo usar para que no se lean los últimos espacios en blanco o  salto de línea ('\n'). Gracias.

Comment: @JoséIgnacio como te comento @abulafia puedes usar `.strip()` en el cual sólo tienes que especificar el tipo de carácter.

Comment: Cuidado, strip también afecta el principio de la cadena. Te conviene usar rstrip (r de right, derecha). Y si no le pasas ningún argumento, elimina todo lo que se considera "espacio en blanco", incluyendo saltos de linea y el caracter " "